# CSS, unable to identify extra space at bottom of 33.33vh elements

Tags: html, css

I am doing a deep dive into CSS perspective and, by extension, parallax.  I have a series of 3 vertical divs which each cover 33.33% of the viewport height.

Everything worked fine until I added the following three attributes:

- overflow-y: scroll in `.wrapper`
- perspective: 2px in `.wrapper`
- transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(1.25); and z-index: -1; in `.parallax::after`

A link to a CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/sfullman/pen/GVNqJw) - next time I'll use jsFiddle for portability sorry.

The extra space is at the bottom and on the right, screenshots here (ignore the play-bar, I had to record it in QuickTime), note the scrollbars and space to bottom/right:

[image: vertical space at bottom]
[image: horizontal space at right]

Using Chrome, I can't find the unaccounted-for space as either margin or padding.  Can anyone help with this?  Just in case it's easier the entire code (which is pretty easy) is below.  Thanks.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
        body, html{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: 200;
            color: brown;
        }
        container{
            x-border: 1px solid #ccc;
            display:block;
            width: 700px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .wrapper {
            /* The height needs to be set to a fixed value for the effect to work.
             * 100vh is the full height of the viewport. */
            height: 100vh;
            /* Enable scrolling on the page. */
            overflow-y: auto;
            /* Set the perspective to 2px. This is essentailly the simulated distance from the viewport to transformed objects.*/
            perspective: 2px;
        }
        .section{
            height: 33.33vh;
            padding: 10px; /* see notes on Step 4 above */
        }
        .parallax1{
            position: relative;
        }
        .parallax1::after{
            position: absolute;
            content: " ";
            top: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            outline: 2px dashed #666;
            background-size: cover;

            transform: translateZ(-2px)  scale(1.25);
            z-index: -1;
        }
        #section1{
            background-color: rgba(254, 228, 198, 0.3);
        }
        #section2{
            background-color: rgba(3, 14, 146, 0.3);
        }
        #section3{
            background-color: rgba(9, 99, 11, 0.3);
        }
        #section1::after {
            background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/900/700');
        }

        #section3::after {
            background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/800/600');
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <container>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="section1" class="section parallax1 bg1">
                <p>Picture One</p>
            </div>
            <div id="section2" class="section static">
                <p>Boring</p>
            </div>
            <div id="section3" class="section parallax1 bg2">
                <p>Picture Two</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </container>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you scaled your element so the space is due to this. visually the element is taking more space adding the scrollbar

Comment: remove the perspective to better notice this

Comment: The `::after` attributes bind the walls to the parent element, and since it is `z-index`ed back, it's smaller. You can visually see it's smaller.  If I scale to `scale(.75)`, same problem.  I removed the scale, same problem.  If I remove perspective, I defeat the whole objective.

Comment: you are missing `box-sizing: border-box` on your element (this explain the scroll without scale) then you can clearly see how the scale create the other spacing issue

Comment: that looked promising, and I did add it.  It did help, the 3 sections are indeed 1/3rd of the `vh`, BUT `div.wrapper` still scrolls vertically and reveals about 20 pixels of whitespace when you scroll down.

Comment: with or without scale?

Comment: ah, the removal of scale solved the bottom space problem.  But without ability to scale up, I can't make the `::after` element as wide as the forefront div.  Any solutions to this?

Comment: OK, I'll answer my own last question: if the last box has an `::after` element that's been transformed back and scaled larger, there may not be a solution, BUT as long as the element with the background is not the last one, and the extra bottom size from scaling doesn't push past what's below, the extra scroll space will not be a problem.